# Can't connect from job to service in kubernetes

Tags: c#, mysql, docker, entity-framework, kubernetes

I'm trying to set up a database migration job for dotnet entity framework.
It seems that I cannot connect to mysql database service from kubernetes job, but I can connect from my desktop when I forward ports.

This is my working MySql deployment + service:

```
kind: Service
metadata:
    name: mysql
spec:
    ports:
        - port: 3306
          targetPort: 3306
    selector:
        app: mysql
    type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mysql
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: mysql
    strategy:
        type: Recreate
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: mysql
        spec:
            containers:
                - image: mysql:8.0
                  name: mysql
                  env:
                    - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
                      value: myDatabase
                    - name: MYSQL_USER
                      value: myUser
                    - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
                      value: myPassword
                    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
                      value: myRootPassword
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 3306
                        name: mysql
                  volumeMounts:
                      - name: mysql-persistent-storage
                        mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
            volumes:
                - name: mysql-persistent-storage
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: mysql-pv-claim
```

I'm not pasting persistent volume claims for brevity.

This works as I'm able to connect to mysql from my desktop after i do:
`kubectl port-forward deployment/mysql 3306:3306` and connect through MySQL Workbench.

What I cannot do is to run migrations from the job that uses Dockerfile which has C# database project with dbContext in order to run db migration.

The job:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: candles-downloader-db-migration
spec:
  backoffLimit: 0
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: candles-service-migration
        image: migration
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        env:
          - name: CONNECTION_STRING
            value: server=mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306;uid=myUser;pwd=myPassword;database=myDatabase
      restartPolicy: Never
```

As you can see I'm passing the connection string via environment variable CONNECTION_STRING

Then there's Dockerfile for the job:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build-env

RUN dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.9
ENV PATH $PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools

WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY ./ .

ENTRYPOINT dotnet ef database update -v --connection $CONNECTION_STRING
```

I have the image built on my minikube cluster.
When the job starts, the dockerfile container gets the connection string. For debugging I used -v flag for verbose output.

Here is the output from the failed job (unimportant parts truncated for brevity): `kubectl logs candles-downloader-db-migration-gqndm`

```
Finding IDesignTimeServices implementations in assembly 'Infrastructure.Persistence.Sql'...
No design-time services were found.
Migrating using database 'myDatabase' on server 'mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306'.
'CandlesServiceDbContext' disposed.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure. Consider enabling transient error resiliency by adding 'EnableRetryOnFailure()' to the 'UseMySql' call.
 ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

I suspect the problems with connection string.
I used `server=mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306;uid=myUser;pwd=myPassword;database=myDatabase`
But I've tried with different server values as well:

- `mysql.default.svc.cluster.local:3306`
- `mysql.default.cluster.local:3306`
- `mysql.svc.cluster.local:3306`
- `mysql:3306`
- even my local cluster ip for the mysql service `10.97.213.180:3306`

None of them works. I always get this error in the job logs:

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Should my job / container on different pod see the mysql server on other pod through the kubernetes service? I thought so, but it looks like it's "invisible".

Comment: Create a busybox pod and try to ping using these service names from the pod. This should give you the correct value. The full name for service can change depend based on namespace where job and mysql lies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after reading kubernetes documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-debugging-resolution/

I've installed DNS utils with the following command:
`kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/admin/dns/dnsutils.yaml`

Then I was able to test my 'mysql' service if it's discoveryable by name:
`kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup mysql`

And it was. The output was:

```
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   mysql.default.svc.cluster.local
Address: 10.97.213.180
```

But after specifying name with port, it failed:
`kubectl exec -i -t dnsutils -- nslookup mysql:3306`

```
Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

** server can't find mysql:3306: NXDOMAIN

command terminated with exit code 1
```

So as I expected the error was in connection string.
I had to change from

```
server=mysql:3306; ...
```

to

```
server=mysql;port=3306; ...
```

and my migrations ran in the job.